# Limit on processes spawned by app runing in a user context. Red Hat

Tags: java, redhat, worker

Is this a limit on the number of worker processes allowed on a non root user account?

The account is running a java -jar file

The environment is Linux Red Hat.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using `ulimit` or `/etc/security/limits.conf`. You can set the hard or soft limit for the number of processes allowed by a group.

```
#<domain>      <type>  <item>         <value>                                                                                                                                                    
#

#*               soft    core            0
#root            hard    core            100000
#*               hard    rss             10000
#@student        hard    nproc           20
#@faculty        soft    nproc           20
#@faculty        hard    nproc           50
#ftp             hard    nproc           0
#ftp             -       chroot          /ftp
#@student        -       maxlogins       4
```

To see the current limit of the maximum number of processes for the oracle user, run:

```
$ su - <username>
$ ulimit -u
```